# convexity of the product of two entropy-like functions

Tags: convex-analysis, information-theory, entropy

Consider the functions $T_p(q)= \sum_i q_i^p$, where p>1 and q is a finite-dimensional vector satisfying $\sum_i q_i = 1, q_i >0$ (ie, a probability mass function).  In information-theoretic terms, these are equivalent (up to constants) to the [Tsallis entropies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsallis_entropy) of q

$T_p$ is a convex function of $q$ for any $p>1$. This is also true of its generalization as a function of (Trace-normalized) Hermitian operators, ie $T_p(A) := Tr(A^p) $

The question is: are products of the form $(T_{p_1})^{r_1}\cdots(T_{p_n})^{r_n}$, where $r_i >1$, also convex?

Note that in general $T_{p_i}, T_{p_j}$ [may define different partial orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359172/do-the-pth-powers-of-p-norms-define-the-same-partial-ordering-on-the-set-of-al), so it would appear that simple arguments that give sufficient conditions for the product of two convex functions to be convex, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27571/convexity-of-the-product-of-two-functions-in-higher-dimensions),  cannot be used. On the other hand, I haven't found any counterexamples yet.